# Nginx load balancer with limit_conn and burst

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, rate-limiting

I currently have multiple backend-servers that are responsible for handling API-requests and one Nginx load balancer that redirects requests to these backend-servers. Since some of these API-requests can be very compute intensive and some clients send a lot of requests at the same time, I want to limit the amount of requests that are sent from the load balancer to the backend-servers per client IP (such that maximum 2 requests for a client are handled simultaneously by the backend). It seems like `limit_conn` can be used to achieve this but with one major limitation. I don't want the load-balancer to respond with an HTTP error in case the client sends 5 requests at once (instead of the maximum 2), but I want the load balancer to keep track of these requests and place them in a queue.

What I really need is a combination of `limit_conn` and the `burst` parameter from `limit_req`. Is anything like this possible? I can't seem to find it.